# Webcam.js How to get 160 by 120 image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-canvas, webcam.js

I have a live stream coming from the camera using webcamjs which is terrific and I am very happy. However it is giving 320 by 240 image and I want some way in which I can show only 160 by 120 to the user.

Is there any way to accomplish this using HTML or JavaScript or jQuery?

Let me describe it more...

In chrome I have limited the display area through CSS by using width and height properties, but when I open in IE, it uses flash and it does not even show up.

```
<form>
.....
.....
<td>Photo</td>
                <td><input id="photo7" type="file" name="photo">
</td>
<div style="width: 320px; height: 240px; clear: right; float: right">
        <div id="takesnap11"
                    style="clear: both; float: right; text-align: center;"></div>
            <div id="my_camera" style="width: 320px; height: 240px; "></div>
            <img id="results2" height="120" width="160" />

        </div>
        <script src="../js/webcam.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script>
    </script>
    </form>
</section>
<script>
function Initiate(){
    Webcam.set({
        image_format: 'jpeg',
        jpeg_quality: 90,
        dest_width: 160,
        dest_height: 120,
        force_flash: false
    });
    Webcam.attach( '#my_camera' );
    document.getElementById("takesnap11").innerHTML='<div onclick="take_snapshot();">Take Snap</div>';
}
function take_snapshot() {
    var data_uri = Webcam.snap();
    document.getElementById('resultssss').innerHTML ='<textarea style="width: 90px;" style="display:none" name="capturedimage"> '+data_uri+'</textarea>';
    document.getElementById('results2').src = data_uri;
}
</script>
<script src="../js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$('#photo7').on('change', function(ev) {
var f = ev.target.files[0];
var fr = new FileReader();

fr.onload = function(ev2) {
    console.dir(ev2);
    $('#results2').attr('src', ev2.target.result);

    document.getElementById('resultssss').innerHTML ='<textarea style="width: 90px;" style="display:none" name="capturedimage"> '+ev2.target.result+'</textarea>';
};

fr.readAsDataURL(f);
});

</script>
```

The user has the option to use a photo upload and hence that photo tag there. I know this is something with the canvas any help appreciated...

Thanks,
Abhijeet.

Comment: You should include your current code and you will get a much better response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** I don't use webcamJS, but...

A quick look at the source code reveals you can set a couple of properties in `Webcam.set` which will cause the image to be cropped:

```
crop_width:160,
crop_height:120,
```

For more info about how it works (using the clipping version of context.drawImage), refer to the source at lines 416-425:

https://github.com/jhuckaby/webcamjs/blob/master/webcam.js

Comment: 'Not working' is not very specific--so here's some general advice on discovering why it's not working. WebcamJS creates the image using canvas's `drawImage` method. Investigate by using your browser's Dev Tool to put break points on the 2 lines of code containing `drawImage`. Then step through the WebcamJS code to discover what is happening. :-)

Comment: What are you using then if you are not using Webcam.js?

Comment: Working nicely.. after changing some more params..!